# Update or delete splitted data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In customers table I have Email column which could contain multiple emails separated by (;).

I used split function to separate emails for each customer:

```
Cust1 --->email1
cust1 --->email2
cust1 ---> emailN
```

And I could add more emails to the same customer.

 I want to be able to update or delete the splitted emails, in other words if email2= `abc@company.com` I want to change it to `xyz@company.com` or delete it.

Is it possible to do using split function? or any other way?

Here is my split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Calling the function to split emails:

```
select tb1.custId, split.splitdata from customers tb1
outer apply [dbo].[fnSplitString] (tb1.email,';') split
where tb1.Email like '%;%'
```

To add new email to the same customer:

```
UPDATE Customers set Email=Email+';new Email' Where CustId='customerId'
```

for updating or deleting existing emails, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should considering redesigning your table.

Comment: yes, completely agree, but it's SAP B1 tables, do not have a choice!

Comment: Then you need a better splitter to start with. The loop is the absolutely slowest way possible to split string in sql server. And even worse than looping it is a multi statement table valued function. Those are just the worst performers. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: To do the kind of update you are talking about you first have to split it, then you have to STUFF it all back together again. What a nightmare. Too bad you are stuck with that table design.

Comment: @SeanLange, for the `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, `REPLACE` will do the trick

Comment: True @FelixPamittan. I meant for new email values. Gosh I hate "tables" like this one. Sad that a major player would produce such rubbish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your split function is not optimal. It's doing the split in an RBAR fashion. There are number of ways to do this in a set-based fashion. Here is one using XML, taken from Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

*I prefer Jeff Moden's [**DelimitedSplit8K**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), but for simplicity's sake, I'll use the XML split.*

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

---

Now that you have your set-based splitter, it's time for the CRUD operations:

To `SELECT` the splitted emails:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerId,
    Email = s.Item
FROM Customer c
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(c.Emails, ';') s
```

---

To `ADD` new `Email` to a particular `Customer`:

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(100) = 'abc@company.com'
UPDATE Customer
    SET Emails = Emails + ';' + @email 
WHERE
    CustomerId = 1
    AND CHARINDEX(@email, Emails) = 0 -- Prevent duplicate Email
```

---

To `UPDATE` an existing `Email` of a `Customer`:

```
DECLARE @to_update NVARCHAR(100) = 'abc@company.com',
        @new_email NVARCHAR(100) = 'xyz@company.com';

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        c.CustomerId,
        Email = CASE WHEN s.Item = @to_update THEN @new_email ELSE s.Item END
    FROM Customer c
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(c.Emails, ';') s
)
UPDATE c
    SET Emails = STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + Email
        FROM Cte
        WHERE CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1, 1, '')
FROM Customer c

SELECT * FROM Customer
```

You could also use `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE Customer
    SET Emails = REPLACE(Emails, @to_update, @new_email)
WHERE CustomerId = 1
```

---

To `DELETE` an existing `Email` from the list:

```
DECLARE @to_delete NVARCHAR(100) = 'abc@company.com';

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        c.CustomerId,
        Email = s.Item
    FROM Customer c
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(c.Emails, ';') s
    WHERE s.Item <> @to_delete
)
UPDATE c
    SET Emails = STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + Email
        FROM Cte
        WHERE CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1, 1, '')
FROM Customer c

SELECT * FROM Customer
```

You could also use `REPLACE`:

```
DECLARE @to_delete NVARCHAR(100) = 'abc@company.com';
UPDATE Customer
    SET Emails = REPLACE(Emails, @to_delete + ';', '')
WHERE CustomerId = 1
```

Now, I'll leave it as exercise for you to convert these into stored procedures. :)

Comment: Won't it allow to add duplicate email in case of `ADD`, if we simply append at the end?

Comment: Yep, we can add an additional check to prevent duplicate.

Comment: Updated to prevent duplicate email in case of `ADD`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FelixPamittan, I could convert these to SPs for sure ;)